# WordPress multisite to a single site - how theme accommodate new WordPress version?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multisite

I am moving a sub-site of a WordPress multi site to a single site. I want to use new WordPress version which is available now. How does the current theme which was once developed for WordPress 3.8.3 can accommodate with new version of WordPress?

Is that advised to use new version while moving a sub-site of multisite to a single site?

Comment: Enable WordPress' [debugging mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and adjust where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. first remove the code

[image]

from there wp-config file after remove this code site will be convert into single site after that you can update.